# PHP regular expression - append a string after occurrences of a needle with partial variable content, but allways a integer variable content

Tags: php, regex

Supose I have a string like this

```
"$c[1]['arts_stock']['art_stock']+$aaa+$c[1234]['abcs_stock']['abc_stock']-$ccc"
```

Yes, it is a string! All I need is to include "[$i]" after each ocurrence of "$c[*nnn*]".

In this case the result needed is

```
"$c[1][$i]['arts_stock']['art_stock']+$aaa+$c[1234][$i]['abcs_stock']['abc_stock']-$ccc
```

If you can, please help.

Comment: Your question looks like a puzzle. While this might be interesting for programmers on the one hand it is hard to understand on the other hand. I would try to breakdown the problem to something more understandable: Simplify the problem. A nice side-effect: Mostly this will also lead you to the solution.

Comment: Have you tried any regular expressions yet?  If so, can you post them?

Comment: Please tell me that you're not using `eval()` on that string later.

Comment: Yes, it is not orthodox, but my project isn't also... see in http://youtu.be/pkpTImGHP3Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Carlos answer works well, you can try this variant:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\$c\[\d+]\K~', '[$i]', $str);
```

`\K` reset all that has been matched before.

Answer (score 3):

Seems easy, but you must remember to escape both `$` and `[]`, as they have meaning inside regular expressions:

```
$str = "\$c[1]['arts_stock']['art_stock']+\$aaa+\$c[1234]['abcs_stock']['abc_stock']-\$ccc";
$str = preg_replace('/\$c\[\d+\]/', '\0[$i]', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

This prints :

```
string(86) "$c[1][$i]['arts_stock']['art_stock']+$aaa+$c[1234][$i]['abcs_stock']['abc_stock']-$ccc"
```

In the `preg_replace` call, `\0` is a backreference to the whole matched text, and so we're telling to replace the matched text, with the matched text plus `[$i]`.